# Maintaining and improving a user journey map

Tags: user-journey, customer-experience, service-design

I want to improve an existing user journey map and am curious about additional layers that can potentially be added to it.

This is a journey map for a travel app. The stages of the journey are 
**Inspiration > Planning > Booking > Preparation > Day of travel > etc.**

The layers it has are  
**Users goal, pain points and opportunities**

Currently I am planning to:

- highlight parts of the journey that are assumptions and come up with an action plan to validate them.
- Update new and upcoming features in the journey that address specific pain-points

What additional layers could be added to the user journey map? Currently there are channel touch-points and emotions of the user. I've seen other user journeys with much more layers.

To encapsulate - is there anything I should look at besides the above?

Comment: That doesn't sound like a journey map.

Comment: Is there a screenshot or sketch of what the journey map looks like or some description of the product or service you are mapping out? @PrashantDubey why doesn't this sound like a journey map to you?

Comment: @MichaelLai I've added some details about what the journey map looks like. thanks for the tip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the main sections of a journey map, its intended use, and other variations - https://www.nngroup.com/articles/journey-mapping-101/

Any other data you want to capture would likely be specific to your project needs. Look at your user research raw data and think about what information is not captured in the journey that can be beneficial to your specific project. Not all data has to be captured, some is irrelevant, some exist better in other type of documents. Regardless, the journey map is a tool to help you communicate and advance your design process, so modify it as you see fit for your needs.